# Get random element from list base on condition

Tags: list, scala, random

I have a list with simple object:

```
case class MyData(name: String, value: String)

val list:List[MyData]
```

I want to select random element with value that is not `"0"` or `""`:

```
val item = list.find(x => x.value != "" && x.value != "0")
```

But it always returns the same one which is the first one.

Comment: You ought to get into the habit of reading the API docs for methods if you're unsure of what they do. The doc for [`List.find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) says "Finds the first element of the sequence satisfying a predicate", so it shouldn't be surprising that it always returns the same element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.util.Random.shuffle(list).find(...)` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try also filtering out those values first, then select a random value from the remaining, namely,

```
list.filter(s => s.value != "" && s.value != "0").maxBy(_ => util.Random.nextInt)
```